# How to set several action for a unique form using struts 1.3?

Tags: java, web

I'm developing  a simple virtual store for an university project. I'm using struts 1.3. My problem is that I have this:

`<action name="ComprarMaisForm" path="/ComprarMais" scope="session" type="com.myapp.struts.ComprarMaisAction">
            <forward name="pagar" path="/pago.jsp"/>
            <forward name="eliminar" path="/vistaCarrito.jsp"/>
            <forward name="comprarmais" path="/index.jsp"/>
    </action>`

I want to have several actions instead of one. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For different type of actions you have to specify different action mappings with different 'paths'

```
<action path="/goto1" ...> .. </action>
<action path="/goto2" ...> .. </action>
```

Anyways If You want to have several actions with same `name` (form-bean name) `scope` `type` and forward mappings (probably silly ques), You need the SAME action, just give same action name wherever you want to use it. 
If any 1 parameter is different you need to specify different `<action/>` mappings.